# Java: Fade out music

Tags: java, audio, mp3, fadeout

I'm making a game. Now if my player goes to another level the music is still playing. Now I want to let the music fade out to let start the new music of the next level.

I use mp3 to play. With the packages: jl1.0, mp3spi1.9.4, tritonus_share-0.3.6.
Oh yeah. Volume is not supported in the FloatControll class.

Comment: I mean: Why did you gave me -1 ?

Comment: Here is a tip: remove the part about "making Braid in Java". It sounds a bit childish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you're trying to get `Volume` control instead of `MasterGain`. Try this:

```
if (line.isControlSupported(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN)) {
    masterGain = (FloatControl) line.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to decrease the mastergain value to -80. With an interval of 0.5f