# Java fade-out running music

Tags: java, audio

How can I fade-out a running audio which is not started via my application..

I want to fade out an other application's music and play mine music for a few seconds using a java application..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Fade out music](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382602/java-fade-out-music)

Comment: I don't think so @kushal .. actually in my case, I want to fade-out an audio that is not started by my application..